# How to transfer a Jquery value to a "inner" table

Tags: jquery

On my webpage (http//:www.hemdrup.no/TESTTEST/master.php) (btw. page is under construction, so styling is not perfect (yet) ) I have a HTML-select. On this SELECT I have 3 weeks. This week and the two next weeks. When I select a week the SELECT.onchange (JS)-function starts an AJAX script. This script fetches data for the chosen week and places this text-block (week-data) in the field 
"txtHint". This part works perfect.

On the left side of the webpage I have the user login. Again using AJAX and place the USER in the field BRUGER (danish for USER) . (If you wanna test it use OLLE as login and BOLLE as password  - dont use any ' or " .

When I click a cell on the loaded datatable (= weekdata) I get the CELL-ID and the content of the cell. That works too. But I need to include the user.

The purpose of this tabel (should work as a time scheduler) is to show use of time. When a registred user clicks on the tabel (user HAS logged in) the Jquery Script shold get the USER (= BRUGER -field ($('#BRUGER').val(); ) on the webpage and include in in the JQuery function (   $('#txtHint').on('click', 'table td', function() ) which it does not. The registred user MUST be loggin in to make any changes in his (or her) schedule. (The name 'jonas' is for test purposes only during construction .)

So question is:  how do I get BRUGER into  $('#txtHint').on('click', 'table td', function() ) ?

(I'm absolutely not sure, but I guess, it because I'm trying to address two different scopes at the same time )...

here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<?php    
  ..... does something useful     
?>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#txtHint').on('click', 'table td', function() 
    {
        alert('test start ');
        var cid = $(this).attr('id');
        alert('id = ' + cid);
        var cval = $(this).text();
        alert('text = ' +  cval);
        var brgr = $('#bruger').val();       // PROBLEM IS HERE !!! 
        alert('bruger = '+ brgr);
        alert('test slut ');
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pasbtn').on('click', function() 
    {
        $("#popup-overlay").css({ visibility: "visible"});
        $("#popup-content").css({ visibility: "visible"});
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clsebtn').on('click', function()
    {
        $("#popup-overlay").css({ visibility: "hidden"});
        $("#popup-content").css({ visibility: "hidden"});
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#loggin").on('click', function()
    {

var username = $('#muser').val();
var password = $('#mpasw').val();

//      str = $("#muser").val() + ";;" + $('#mpasw').val();
//      alert($("#muser").val() + " -- " + $('#mpasw').val() + " -- " + str);

        $("#popup-overlay").css({ visibility: "hidden"});
        $("#popup-content").css({ visibility: "hidden"});

        $(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'getdata.php',
            data: ({username:username, password: password }),
            success: function(data) 
            {
         //     alert(data);
                $('#bruger').html(data);
            }
        });
      });
    });
});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
html
{
    z-index:        1;    
}

.popup-overlay
{
  /* Hides pop-up when there is no "active" class */

    visibility:     hidden;  
    position:       absolute;
    background:     #ffffff;
    border:         3px solid #666666;
    width:          50%;
    height:         50%;
    left:           25%; 
    z-index:        10;
    border-radius:  15px;   


}
.popup-overlay.active
{
  /* displays pop-up when "active" class is present */

  visibility:       hidden;  
  text-align:       center;
}

.popup-content 
{
  /* Hides pop-up content when there is no "active" class */ 

  visibility:       hidden; 
}

.popup-content.active 
{
  /* Shows pop-up content when "active" class is present */

 visibility:        visible;
}

button
{
  display:          inline-block;
  vertical-align:   middle;
  border-radius:    30px;
  margin:           .20rem;
  font-size:        1rem;
  color:            #666666;
  background:       #ffffff;
  border:1px solid  #666666;  
}

button:hover
{
  border:           1px solid #666666;
  background        :#666666;
  color:            #ffffff;
}

button2
{
/*
  display:          inline-block;
  vertical-align:   middle;
  border-radius:    30px;
  margin:           .20rem;
  font-size:        1rem;
  color:            #666666;
  height:           50px;        
  background:       #lightblue;
  border:1px solid  #666666;  
*/
}


.pos22
{
position:   absolute;
left:       150px;
top:        25px;
width:      100px;
height:     25px;
border:     1px solid black;

}

.passblok
{
    position:   Absolute;
    left:       750px;
    top:        155px;
    width:      250px;
    height:     65px;
    border:     2px solid black;
    border-radius:  25px;
    background-color:   lightgreen;
}

.admblok
{
    position:   Absolute;
    left:       965px;
    top:        570px;
    width:      50px;
    height:     25px;
    font-family:    Arial;
    font-size:      8px;
}



.pos2
{
    position:   Absolute;
    left:       50px;
    top:        325px;              /* 100px */
    width:      950px;
    height:     235px;
    border:     1px solid blue;
    overflow:   auto;
}


.klokkeblok
{
    position:   Absolute;
    left:       200px;
    top:        290px;              /* 100px */
    width:      200px;
    height:     25px;
    border:     1px solid blue;
}

.selform
{
    position:   absolute;
    left:       50px;
    top:        275px;
    width:      105px;
}

TR
{
    height:     25px;
}

TD
{
    height:         25px;
    width:          100px;
    text-align:     Center;
    font-family:    Verdana;
    font-size:      12px; 
}
.td2
{
  width:            35%;
}

.td3
{
  width:            35%;
  background-color: lightblue;   
}

input
{
    border:         1px solid black;
}

.brg
{
    position:       absolute;
    left:           750px;
    top:            285px;
    width:          200px;
    height:         25px;
    font-family:    Arial;
}


</style>


<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        else 
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<?php

function showweek($date,$weeks)
{
    $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d,m,Y',$date);
    $dateTime->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString($weeks. 'weeks'));
    $dateTime->modify('next monday');
    return $dateTime->format('W').' / '.$dateTime->format('d-m-Y')  ;
}


    $year  = date('Y'); 
    $day   = date('d');
    $month = date('m'); 
    $date = $day.','.$month.','.$year;
    $weeks = -1;
    $uge = showweek($date,$weeks).'<BR>';
    $weeks = 0;
    $uge1 = showweek($date,$weeks).'<BR>';
    $weeks = 1; 
    $uge2 = showweek($date,$weeks).'<BR>';
?>

<body>
    <div class="popup-overlay" id="popup-overlay">          <!--Creates the popup body-->
        <div class="popup-content" id="popup-content">      <!--Creates the popup content-->
            <center><h2>LOGIN BOKS</h2>
            <p> INDTAST BRUGER:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" id="muser" size='18' value=""></p>
            <P> INDTAST PASSORD:&nbsp; <input type="password" id="mpasw" size='18' value=""></p>
            <P>&nbsp;</P>
            <button class="close" id="clsebtn">LUK </button>        <!--popup's close button-->
            <button class="close" id="loggin">LOG IND </button>     <!--popup's close button-->
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brg" id='bruger' name='bruger'>BRUGER:</div>
    <div class="selform">
        Velg uge her:<BR>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <option value="">Velg en UGE:</option>  
            <option value="<?php echo $uge ?>">Uge <?php echo $uge ?></option>
            <option value="<?php echo $uge1 ?>">Uge <?php echo $uge1 ?></option>
            <option value="<?php echo $uge2 ?>">Uge <?php echo $uge2 ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="klokkeblok">
        <b>Tidspunkt og dato.. her </b>
    </div>
    <div id="txtHint" class="pos2">
        <b>Tabel data her... </b>
    </div>
    <div class="passblok" id='passblok'>
        <button class='button2' id='pasbtn'>LOGIN</button>    
    </div>  
    <div class="admblok">
        <a href="privat.php">ADM</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So question is:

Comment: i think you need to use `$('#bruger').text()` since your `$('#bruger')` is a `div`

Comment: HEJ Just tried it- did not work

Comment: When you have logged in, what does you `$('#bruger')` html looks like?

Comment: Sorry, it works, forgot to reset page .. After reset NO-problem(s).

Comment: Tak for hjælpen. !!!  (thanks for the help !)

Comment: No problem, happy to help